# How to put a "=>" symbol of one line just below "=" of another one?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am writing LaTeX in Google Colab using the code below,

```
$$mean \ of \ apples = \frac{sum \ of \ apples}{number \ of \  children}$$
\
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1725}{6} = 287.5$$
```

And I get this output -

[image]

How can I make it so that the "=>" from the second line is just below the "=" from the first line. Something like this -

```
mean of apples = sum of apples / number of children
               => 1725/6
               => 287.5
```

Comment: If it really is LaTeX you could here use split from amsmath, but the correct symbol to use here is not the Rightarrow, but an equal sign.

Comment: I am not sure about Google Colab so it might be wrong, but have you tried using the `align`/`aligned` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MWE that accomplishes the desired alignment is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
mean \ of \ apples & = \frac{sum \ of \ apples}{number \ of \  children} \\
& \Rightarrow \frac{1725}{6} = 287.5
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Correct Alignment on equation]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell which software or website did you use to write this?

Comment: I used [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com) to create this specific example. It is an online LaTeX editor. I'm not entirely sure whether this applies to Google Colab or not.

Answer (score 4):

Problem of aligning of equation is solved by @8aa answer (+1), but for writing of texts in equation should not be used variables as is done in question as well in mentioned answer. Correct is use of upright text, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textup{mean of apples} 
    & = \frac{\textup{sum of apples}}{\textup{number of children}} \\[1ex]
    & \Rightarrow \frac{1725}{6} = 287.5
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** considered is @Barbara Beton comment.

[image]

Comment: Much better than`\mbox`, use the command  `\text{ }` defined in `amstext` package which is loaded by the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Actually, if you want to make sure that the text is upright, even in a theorem environment (where `\text` will follow the style of the surrounding text and result in italic), `\textup` will do that for you.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, you are right.  I will correct answer accordingly ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell which software or website did you use to write this?

Comment: @IshanShishodiya, for beginner you should read some introductory text about LaTeX.  For example *The Not So Short
Introduction to LATEX2"* available on https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/?lang=en. BTW, for writing math people care that is simple to distinguish text from variables. The former use upright fonts, the later slanted. So from this aspect your way to writing equations (and selected answer) is wrong.

Comment: @Zarko Okay, I'll keep that in mind from now onwards. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @IshanShishodiya, why not already for this document (for which you asked for help)? :-)